# How can I use a placeholder with a number input in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I have a number input in a form like follows :

```
<input
  type="number"
  id="weight"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  value={this.state.weight}
  placeholder="Enter weight…"
/>
```

How can I have a placeholder phrase display on it ?

If I initialy set `this.state.weight` to value `0`, then no placeholder displays.

If I set it to `null` the placeholder displays but get this ugly warning

> Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be
>   null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or
>   `undefined` for uncontrolled components.

Answer (score 10):

You can use: `weight: ""`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    weight: "",
  };

  handleChange = e => this.setState( { weight: e.target.value } )

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="weight"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.weight}
          placeholder="Enter weight…"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you want a number at the end of the change, then you can use:

```
handleChange = e => this.setState( { weight: e.target.valueAsNumber } )
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
 class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
  super(props);
    this.state = {weight:undefined}
   }
   render(){
  return(
   <input
          type="number"
          id="weight"
          value={this.state.weight}
          placeholder="Enter weight…"
        />
  )
   }
 }

 ReactDOM.render(
 <App/>,
 document.getElementById("root")
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Define `weight` with `undefined` that will work.

```
this.state = {
    weight:undefined
};
```

Comment: This causes the component to become uncontrolled before entering any value, and controller after changing the inputs. React throws a warning in this case.

Comment: @AliTou  is correct, this causes React to throw a warning, and this is not a recommended solution. The way to solve this without throwing warnings is to use an empty string instead of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You need the empty value to render an empty string, with a `null` default value. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/193576/)

```
 <input
    type="number"
    id="weight"
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ age: e.target.value })}
    value={this.state.age || ''}
    placeholder="Enter weight…" />
  />
```

React still considers an `<input type="number"` to be an `input`, and it needs to be [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9

Yes, we intentionally treat undefined and null differently, as does JS. Basically, reading the spec definitions is our explanation.
*as stated, **NULL VALUE : primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value***

Testing for the something which is not actually present is not something I would recommend.

```js
<input
    type="number"
    id="weight"
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ age: e.target.value })}
    value={this.state.age || undefined}
    placeholder="Enter weight…" />
 />
```

this is what you are probably lookin' for!